# Xpath Error: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document':

Tags: robotframework

Iam using below xpath:

```
//label[text()='First Name']/Parent::div/following-sibling::div/div/input[@disabled='disabled']
```

But showing an error as:

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
>   '//label[text()='First
>   Name']/Parent::div/following-sibling::div/div/input[@disabled='disabled']'
>   is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: how are yo uusing that xpath? Can you show the keyword that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all - the expression is invalid. The issue is in the `parent` axis - it has to be in small caps, not capitalized as you've set it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to make a shorter Xpath, because seems long Xpath are hard to read, so as an example you can try with:

```
//button[contains(text(),'Yes')]
```

or

```
//button[contains(.,'Yes')]
```

Make a shorter Xpath worked for me.